# Search through list with duplicates

Tags: python, list, search, duplicates

I have a list that looks like this:

```
 list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,9,2]
```

If I were to say

```
 if 2 in list1:
      print True
```

It prints True once. Is there a way to determine if 2 or any variable x is in the list multiple times and if so how many without iterating through the entire list like this?

```
for item in list1:
      if item = 2:
          duplicates +=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,9,2]

dict1 = {}

for ele in list1:
    # you iterate through the list once
    if ele in dict1:
        # if a key is already in the dictionary
        # you increase the corresponding value by one
        dict1[ele] += 1 
    else:
        # if a key is not yet in the dictionary
        # you set its corresponding value to one
        dict1[ele] = 1
```

Result:

```
>>> dict1
{1: 1, 2: 2, 4: 1, 6: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}
```

Comment: I almost down-voted this---this is exactly what a counter does for you already. `import collections as col` then `col.Counter(list1)` and you're done/

Comment: @BenDundee, yes `Counter` does exactly that, and it was probably worth mentioning. I got an impression that OP would also like an explanation about what's going on, that's why a "long" answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for `list.count`:

```
if list1.count(2) > 1:
    print True
```

In [Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

> s.count(i)  total number of occurrences of i in s

Of course under the covers, the `count` method will iterate through the entire `list` (although it will do so a lot faster than a `for` loop). If you're trying to avoid that for performance reasons, or so you can use a lazy iterator instead of a `list`, you may want to consider other options. For example, `sort` the list and use `itertools.groupby`, or feed it into a `collections.Counter`, etc.

Comment: You should generalize this into a method for any `x`. Regardless, +1.

Comment: I was just talking about the OP saying any x. You're correct.

Comment: @squiguy: Do you think I need to clarify that? If so, I can add more to the answer, no problem. But hopefully, even if the OP (or a future searcher) is a total novice who doesn't get that immediately, the quote from the docs will make it clear?

Comment: I think it's clear. As you added more and more edits, my comments became superfluous :). My apologies.

Comment: @squiguy: No problem; comments that help make the answer better only look superfluous after the fact.

Answer (score 4):

```
from collections import Counter
y = Counter(list1)
print y[2]
print y[5] # and so on
```

Comment: If you do a `from collections import Counter`, you need to do `Counter(list1)`, not `collections.Counter(list1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [1,2,4,6,8,9,2]
print list1.count(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `collections.Counter` object for this:

```
from collections import Counter
myCounter = Counter(list1)

print myCounter[2] > 1 #prints 'True'
```

If you only plan on doing this with one or a few elements of the list, I would go with [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864128/1142167), however.

Comment: You don't need `myCounter.get(2, 0)`; 0 is already the default for `myCounter[2]`.

Comment: @abarnert: Oh, awesome! Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Collections.counter (as others have pointed out) is how I would do this. However, if you really want to get your hands dirty:

```
def count(L):
    answer = {}
    for elem in L:
        if elem not in answer:
            answer[elem] = 0
        answer[elem] += 1
    return answer

>>> counts = count(myList)
>>> duplicates = [k for k,v in counts.iteritems() if v>1]
```

Comment: This is just building a (slightly less powerful equivalent to a) `Counter` manually. Also, you mean `counts.iteritems()`, not `myList.iteritems()`, right?

Comment: @abarnert: you're right. Which is why I mentioned that it's a "getting your hands dirty" way of doing it. I'd also mentioned that I would have otherwise used `Collections.Counter`. Also, thanks for the bug-report (fixed!)